# On click fill another divs content from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, css

I need to make a functionality that when I click on one element another elements content gets filled from bottom to top.

I have tried to achieve it with triggering hover because I have this working If I hover over element itself

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click-me').on('click', function(){
       $('.button-grey').trigger('hover');
  })
})
```

```css
.button-grey {
    padding: 13px 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #969496;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fff 50%, #969496 50%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    color: transparent;
}
.button-grey:before {
    content:"";
    z-index:-1;
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #969496 50%, transparent 50%);

}

.button-grey,
.button-grey:before {
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-position: top;
    transition: background-position 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.button-grey:hover,
.button-grey:hover:before{
    background-position: bottom;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="click-me">Click me</div>
<div class="button-grey"></div>
```

So this trigger thing doesnt work and I am not sure if thats the way of doing this.
My desired outcome is that on clicking one element other button gets filled.
Here is picture of what I need
https://ibb.co/3Mq8PzL

Comment: Do you need it to fill on the `hover` **and** on the `click` of the other div?

Comment: Only on click...that hover is basically only my way of thinking not an actual valid concept

Comment: Fair enough - then definitely look at @cloned's answer, as that is the way I'd do it as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really trigger hover that way. I think this will only trigger it for 1ms or so (since you don't really hover over it) and you don't see anything.

One solution is to use a class for this and toggle the class on click:

```
.button-grey_fakehover,
.button-grey_fakehover:before{
    background-position: bottom;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here we add definitions for some `button-grey_fakehover` class (the name is totally up to you tough)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.click-me').on('click', function(){
       $('.button-grey').toggleClass('button-grey_fakehover');
  })
})
```